# What is an idiomatic way to generate a sequence of graphs from networkx.optimal_edit_paths?

Tags: python, sequence, networkx, graph-theory, edit-distance

I recently learned [how to interpret the output of networkx.optimal_edit_paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73696000/how-to-interpret-output-of-networkx-optimal-edit-paths), and I am interested in generating a sequence of graphs based on the sequences of edits.

Let us suppose the example from the NetworkX documentation:

```py
import networkx as nx
G1 = nx.cycle_graph(4)
G2 = nx.wheel_graph(5)
paths, cost = nx.optimal_edit_paths(G1, G2)
```

And let us suppose that we want to generate a sequence of graphs only using the edits given in `paths[0]`. While there does exist methods such as [`networkx.Graph.remove_nodes_from`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.remove_nodes_from.html), [`networkx.Graph.remove_edges_from`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.remove_edges_from.html), and their `add` counterparts, they don't seem to be suited to handling the `None`s or for doing so in a way that obtains a sequence of graphs.

While I could certainly code some loops and control flow of my own, is there an idiomatic way of doing this in `networkx`?